# subset data in sas using macro properly and append them to a file

Tags: macros, sas, sas-macro

I have some data sets that I wrote some code to clean according to some methods according to some biological literature and then I want to split it into day and night (because they must be analyzed separately). It worked but now I need to do this for the full set which is WAY to many files for me to want to deal with one by one. So I am now trying to write a macro to split it into days and nights for me..

My data looks like so

```
   Hour         var1      var2      var3
     1            123       90       100
     2            122       99       108
     ...........
     4            156       80       120
     4            156       80       145
     4            143       82       132
```

basically night has 1 obs per hour day 3. I also have this for many days.

Each dataset is named STUDYIDID#_first or STUDYID_ID#_last. I want to generate four datasets per dataset.
So MYID111_first would create: MYID111_first_day_var1, MYID111_first_day_var2, MYID111_first_night_var1 , and MYID111_first_night_var2.

I would then LIKE to append them into 4 datasets:
MYID_A_first_day_var1, MYID_A_first_day_var2, MYID_A_first_night_var1 , and MYID_A_first_night_var2.

MY CODE SO FAR:

```
   %macro datacut(libname,worklib=work, grp = _A ,time1 = _night , time2 = _day type1 = _var1 , type2 = _var2);


   %local num i;
      proc datasets library=&libname memtype=data nodetails;
      contents out=&worklib..temp1(keep=memname) data=_all_ noprint;
    run;

   data _null_;
      set &worklib..temp1 end=final;
      by memname notsorted;
      if last.memname;
      n+1;
      call symput('ds'||left(put(n,8.)),trim(memname));

      if final then call symput('num',put(n,8.));

   run;

   %do i=1 %to &num;

   /* do the artifact removing method */
   DATA &libname..&&ds&i; 
   SET &libname..&&ds&i; 
       PT_ID = '&ds&i' ;
       IF var1< 60 OR var1> 230 then delete; 
       IF var2< 30 OR var2> 230 THEN delete; 
       IF var3< 60OR var3 > 135 THEN DELETE; 
       IF var2 > var1 then delete; 
   run;
   /* get just the night values */
   PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE &libname..&&ds&i&time1 as
        SELECT * 
        FROM &libname..&&ds&i 
        WHERE Hour BETWEEN 0 and 6 OR Hour BETWEEN 22 and 24
        order by systolic
    ; 
    QUIT;
    /* trim off the proper number of observations for variable 1 */
    DATA &libname..&&ds&i&time1&type1; 
    SET &libname..&&ds&i&time1  end=eof; 
        IF _N_ =1 then delete;  
        if eof then delete; 
    run;
   PROC append base= &libname..&&ds&time1&type1 
   data= &libname..&&ds&i&time1;
   run;

QUIT;


   %end;
%mend datacut;


%datacut(work)
```

Now the initial datastep works correctly but the later ones don't rename the data as planned. I get a bunch of datasets called Ds10_night_var1 with the wrong field names (memtype, nodetails, data)

I get the warning:

```
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference DS1_NIGHT not resolved.
NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "TIME1".
1      work.&ds1_night
            -
            22
            200
ERROR 22-322: Expecting a name.

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds

WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference DS1_NIGHT_SYS not resolved.


22: LINE and COLUMN cannot be determined.
NOTE 242-205: NOSPOOL is on. Rerunning with OPTION SPOOL might allow recovery of the LINE and
              COLUMN where the error has occurred.
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, /, ;,
              _DATA_, _LAST_, _NULL_.
201: LINE and COLUMN cannot be determined.
NOTE: NOSPOOL is on. Rerunning with OPTION SPOOL might allow recovery of the LINE and COLUMN
      where the error has occurred.
ERROR 201-322: The option is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

So I want the right names for my file AND my datasets to actually have data I and I don't understand why they don't.

Comment: I don't think you need a macro here at all.  If you name your datasets such that the night datasets start with night and day start with day you can use dataset variable list short cut with a colon.

Comment: I need to cut it into day and night right now it's all of them. and it would over write. I have solved this by making one macro for day var1, one for night var 1 one for day var 2 and one for day var 2.... then another macro to append I found on the documentation... I think this is needlessly complicated to make 4 macros then repeat for every set of data but whatever it's still faster than doing each at a time...

Comment: Run your macro with `option mprint symbolgen` on to see where the error is. Right now hard to see what step is generating the error. My guess is your have an extra `&` somewhere. Also, macro variables only resolve in double quotes for your PT_ID.

Comment: Maybe you want: &&ds&i..&time1

Comment: do not have time to test this out but you probably would like to enclose your macro with double quotes instead of single quotes / and separate your macro variables with a '.' e.g. . &&ds&i.&time1.&type1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, you write a macro variable as `&` followed by its name, optionally followed by `.`. With this `.` you can explicitly end the macro variable reference, so you can use a macro variable as a prefix, like in

```
%let prefix = fore;
Aspect = &prefix.Ground;
```

which evaluates to `Aspect = foreGround;`. And that is why

```
%let myLib = abc;
%let mymember = xyz;
data &myLib.&myMember;
```

is an error, as it evaluates to `data abcxyz;`, and you must write

```
data &myLib..&myMember; 
** or as I prefer **;
data &myLib..&myMember.;
```

to get `data abc.xyz;`.

For the case you need macro variables to create macro variable names from, SAS allows to write double ampersands `&&`, which evaluate to a single `&` and continues evaluating until all ampersands are consumed. So suppose

```
%let i = 1;
%let ds1 = myData;
%let time = _nigth;
```

This is how SAS evaluates `&&ds&i&time1` :

- `&&ds&i&time1`
- `&ds1_night`
- ERROR because a macro variable `ds1_night` is not defined

This is how SAS evaluates `&&ds&i..&time1.` :

- `&&ds&i..&time1.`
- `&ds1._night`
- `myData_night`

Comment: Good answer. Slight suggestion to reword 'if there is a dot after the name, it is considered part of the macro variable.'  Maybe 'if there is a dot after the name, it explicitly ends the macro variable reference (variable name) and the dot is consumed during the evaluation process.'